# How do I reinstall all installed packages in Alpine Linux?

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux, reinstall, apk-tools

I'm having some issues with my system and I would like to reinstall packages to see if that resolves it, but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing this. How do I reinstall all installed packages in Alpine Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using a combination of `apk info` and `apk fix`:

```
$ apk info | xargs sudo apk fix
```

Be careful however as this may break your system if you do not have enough storage available to reinstall every package.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something wrong with this suggestion?